# My logon and logout taking too much time ! is there a way to make them fast ?

Tags: login, performance, restart

I regularly use bleachbit to clean my system. Though Login and Logout now taking lots of time.Is there a way to make at least Login faster ?

I have done some Kernel updates. I have three different version of kernels now. Does this causing the slow startup ?? I every time select a kernel, then a red screen appears for almost 14 sec then comes up the Ubuntu screen. and lastly login screen.

I want to just go into the login screen after selecting kernel. Is there a way to do something like that ? How can i make system start faster ?

Comment: Please provide more information about it. what is the ubuntu version you use, what is the kernel you use. try older kernels instead of your current one, are they run smoothly than the new one?

Comment: Im ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric 32 bit dual booted with windows 7 Ultimate x64. RAM 4GB

Comment: Have you installed the display drivers from the additional drivers tool? the red screen(or any other color) appears when the system is booting, the other part- ubuntu screen is a part of the booting process. there is no way to skip booting and jump to login screen!. but if you have installed drivers and do not want that red screen do this http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html

Comment: Nope ! no extra drivers. But this is not the screen Im talikng about:http://lh3.ggpht.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TLeEaO4PDjI/AAAAAAAACI4/DMZMO9a3Q_c/s2000/ubuntu-plymouth.png. There is a another completely blank red screen appears before that  plymouth screen. I want to skip that screen.

Comment: Yes I know bro! I had the same problem with the ubuntu 11.10 version. the red (Sometimes it changes) color screen is a part of the booting process. then after sometime, it shows the ubuntu screen with plymouth theme. in my case, I followed that link and it worked. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the main reason for being my startup too much slow is the Wubi Installation. If you want a fast working OS then you need to install it in a separate drive.

Im using Wubi and I have installed Ubuntu on top of Windows 7, Thats why it taking too much time to read(mount) things from HDD.